# SharpDX Texture2D to Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, texture2d, sharpdx

I have a problem with using SharpDX. I convert a Bitmap, lock the bits with the lockBits method and then create a DataStream and build a Texture2D from it. This seems to work quite well, no error occurs.
Now I have the following problem. I want to convert the Texture2D back to a Bitmap. There is a method called Texture2D.ToStream(size, texture2D, stream) but when I try this only an error occurs.
Can anyone help me with this issue? A conversion to an Image or WriteableBitmap would be also okay.

Comment: What directx version are you using? (10/11 or d2d)

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099845/convert-slimdx-direct3d11-texture2d-to-net-bitmap/47072283#47072283

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:

```
var inputTex2D = Texture2D.FromStream<Texture2D>(device, inputMemoryStream, (int)inputMemoryStream.Length, new ImageLoadInformation()
        {
            Depth = 1,
            FirstMipLevel = 0,
            MipLevels = 0,
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
            BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
            Filter = FilterFlags.None,
            MipFilter = FilterFlags.None,
        });
```

My DirectX Version is 11.0